# How do I change the below query to pull by day and not month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select, count

How do I change the below query to pull by day and not month?

```
select CONVERT(CHAR(4), dCompletedDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), dCompletedDate, 120) as MonthYear,
count(case when dCompletedDate is not null then 1 else 0 end) as 'Total Completes'
from TProfile a
left join TStudyTable b
on a.lhouseholdid=b.lhouseholdid
where
dcompleteddate >= '1/1/1990' and dcompleteddate < '1/1/2050'
group by CONVERT(CHAR(4), dCompletedDate, 100) + CONVERT(CHAR(4), dCompletedDate, 120)
order by MonthYear
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dcompleteddate` is of `datetime` datatype, you can just `cast` it to a `date`:

```
select 
    cast(dcompleteddate as date) as dcompletedday,
    count(*) as total_completes
from tprofile 
left join tstudytable s on p.lhouseholdid = s.lhouseholdid
where dcompleteddate >= '1990-01-01' and dcompleteddate < '2050-01-01'
group by cast(dcompleteddate as date)
order by dcompletedday
```

Side notes:

- I changed the conditional `count()` to just `count(*)`; you are filtering on `dcompleteddate` so it is guaranteed to be not `null` (and even if it was, you current expression would still count `null` values)
- I also changed the `where` clause to use literal dates that are more standard